# Avoid an image to go outside a div?

Tags: css, html, crop

I have:

```
<div style="height:15px">
    <img src="image" />
</div>
```

The image is bigger than 15px, so it's outside the div when you see it. How do I "crop" the image (show only the 15px port of it), only using css?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need `overflow:hidden` see an example here:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/S8qAq/

Read about `overflow`: [here W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Good luck!

Comment: Not the first, but most complete answer, with a working example (I tested as well). Well done, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try giving an `overflow:hidden` to the div.

Answer (score 3):

add `overflow:hidden;` to your div style.

Answer (score 2):

Use the overflow css property:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised no one has suggested `object-fit: cover;`

Comment: It could be because this has no IE support, according to MDN.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `overlow: hidden`,  `object-fit: cover;` and `width: fit-content` they come with their own hurdles. If you have more than one image, then these methods may not provide you with the best solution.
2. Instead, you can define parent element size and force children to fit inside accordingly with `max-height` and `max-width`

```
<div style="height:15px; width: 15px;">
    <img src="image" style="max-height:100%; max-width: 100%;">
</div>
```