# Image goes outside div when browser is resized

Tags: html, css

I put together something that I thought was pretty straight forward. However, one of the images is causing me trouble when I re-size the browser. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/how-do-i-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-a-div-container), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336765/image-jumps-out-of-div-when-browser-is-resized), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328625/avoid-an-image-to-go-outside-a-div) to try to figure out why the image is jumping out of the div. I add the `overflow: hidden;` and then I tried to readjust `min-width` to 500, where it was previously 767.

css

```
.contact-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  color: white;
  background: url(../images/Death_to_stock_Marzocco_Coffee_10.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .content-section {
    padding-top: 250px;
  }
```

html

```
<!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="contact" class="contact-section text-center">
    <div class="contact-section">
      <div class="container">
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <!--<p>contact us</p> -->
                  <ul class="list-inline banner-social-buttons">
                      <li>
                        <a href="mailto:me@domain.com" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Email</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="https://twitter.com/user" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Twitter</span></a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I am getting two problems:
1) The image spills when I resize (image 1)
2) The div image appears to be distorted (image 2)

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**
Problem 1 was due to mistakenly including an older css file in the directory that was overwriting the `body`
Problem 2 was solved by adding `no-repeat` as mentioned by several commentors

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Comment: take out the `repeat` from your `background-image` property, that should solve the second issue.

Comment: Removed `repeat` but image renders the same as the attached image

Comment: `background-repeat`'s default behavior is `repeat`, meaning if you remove it, it will still repeat. You have to set it to `background-repeat: no-repeat;`, or in the case of your code, `background: url(../images/Death_to_stock_Marzocco_Coffee_10.jpg) no-repeat center center;`

Comment: @TylerRoper thanks! That was helpful

Comment: @TylerRoper +1 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you applying your image (contact-section)class to two tags maybe that has some kind of bad effect

```
<section id="contact" class="contact-section text-center">
    <div class="contact-section">
```

Answer (score 1):

add no-repeat

background: url(../images/Death_to_stock_Marzocco_Coffee_10.jpg) no-repeat     center center;

also add 
     background-size:contain; to .contact-section property to scale the background image.

Comment: @avipatel Hmm. I added contain by `background-size: cover contain;` Can it only be cover or contain?

Comment: @Jebediah15 Correct - it's one or the other. `cover` means "scale the background-image so that it covers the entirety of the div" (the background will most likely be cropped), whereas `contain` means "Scale the background so that the entire background-image is visible"

Comment: @TylerRoper awesome. Thanks for that explanation--as you can tell I'm a beginner